# join sphinx results on external mysql data constraints

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sphinx

I'm trying to do sphinx search with a limited result set based on a mysql table has a user to network relationship.
So they should only be able to search within networks they are a member of.  Since there is a near infinite amount of possible user to network combinations the only way I've been able to accomplish this is to do the sphinx search and than add it to a mysql query that joins it on the network table and includes an IN statement with the list of document IDs.

This is very efficient and I've already noticed as the site gets larger that this would be a really big issue.

When the data in sphinx was in a mysql fulltext column this wasn't an issue. but every since we added sphinx for the faster searching its complicated the way we get the final results.

I've thought about doing the opposite, getting a list of all networks the user is in and then doing a sphinx search with that as a limiting factor (a network id attribute).

Does anyone have a better solution for this? Is there anyway i can join this data directly on the sphinx data and limit it by a mysql result set?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add an example of the mysql query you originally run (ie before sphinx)? I suspect it would be a case of adding a bunch of user_ids as a MVA on each document, but its not clear what exact queries you want to run.

Comment: MySQL 5.6 now includes fulltext search capabilities for the Innodb Storage engine: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html